# OpenCV putText writes previous values on top

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use the cv2.putText() function to write some values to an image and then save it. I have a folder of n images and when I run my script, the first image looks fine. The text is clear. But for every image after that it remembers the value from the previous images and writes that along with the new one. Here is an example:

[image]

I am not sure how this happens. I wrote a function to do this 1 image at a time so I figured after the function is done executing the memory location with the values gets erased. The function I wrote to accomplish this:

```
def write_to_image(filename, draw_window, draw_face):
    file_path = 'images/original/' + filename
    img = cv2.imread(file_path)
    if(len(draw_window) < 1):
        print("No windows were identified to draw.")
    else:
        for data in range(0, len(draw_window), 3):
            u_value = draw_window[data]
            x_coordiante = draw_window[data + 1]
            y_coordinate = draw_window[data + 2]
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
            bottom_left_corner_of_text = (x_coordiante, y_coordinate)
            font_scale = .5
            font_color = (255, 0, 0)
            line_type = 1
            cv2.putText(img, "Window: " + ('%.2f' % float(u_value)), bottom_left_corner_of_text, font, font_scale, font_color, line_type)
            bottom_left_corner_of_text = (x_coordiante + 50, y_coordinate)
            cv2.putText(img, "Window Q: " + ('%.2f' % float(heatloss_algorithm(u_value))), bottom_left_corner_of_text, font, font_scale,
                        font_color, line_type)
    if(len(draw_face) < 1):
        print("No face was identified to draw.")
    else:
        for data in draw_face:
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
            bottom_left_corner_of_text = (530, 500)
            font_scale = .5
            font_color = (255, 0, 255)
            line_type = 1
            cv2.putText(img, "Face: " + ('%.2f' % float(data)), bottom_left_corner_of_text, font, font_scale, font_color, line_type)
            bottom_left_corner_of_text = (500, 460)
            value = heatloss_algorithm(data)
            cv2.putText(img, "Face Q: " + ('%.2f' % float(value)), bottom_left_corner_of_text,
                        font, font_scale,
                        font_color, line_type)
    cv2.imwrite('images/ann/' + filename, img)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What exactly is the issue and why is it occurring? Am I wrong in my assumptions of how functions work in python?

Solution: "try clearing draw_wimdow and/or draw_face afterwards" -Micka

Comment: try clearing draw_wimdow and/or draw_face afterwards

Comment: You are a beautiful human. That worked thank you so much!